# How to load images and labels in Torch for a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, torch

I'm new to Torch and would like to load some images from two directories (one for each label).  I'm trying to build a convolutional neural network that will classify images as belonging to one class or another (i.e. a binary classifier) but I am unsure how load images, label those images and get the data into the correct format.  I'm using the following tutorial, however the training data is loaded in a different way which I am not familiar with.

http://code.madbits.com/wiki/doku.php?id=tutorial_supervised

Hope someone can help me get started and point me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the format of images that you want to load. In any case, you should use [image](https://github.com/torch/image) package and put loaded images in one `torch.Tensor`. I suggest also [this](https://github.com/soumith/cvpr2015/blob/master/Deep%20Learning%20with%20Torch.ipynb) tutorial, where you can find a lot of tips on NN construction and data manipulation.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680984/does-input-dimension-resolution-affect-the-performance-of-convolutional-neural-n/47684223#47684223

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check  [this link](https://github.com/torch/demos/tree/master/train-face-detector)
The data.lua file in that is very simple to understand. They have used torch tensors, and the code is self explanatory. I had achieved a clear understanding of loading the data, post reading this link; hope it helps you too.

Comment: I think that part of the problem that the user is having is that the demo says that the data is loaded in .t7 format but when you go to the streetview numbers website the data is in .mat format. How do you go form one format to the other assuming you do not have MATLAB?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680984/does-input-dimension-resolution-affect-the-performance-of-convolutional-neural-n/47684223#47684223