# Does input dimension/resolution affect the performance of Convolutional Neural Networks?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, keras

I am building a image classifier in which I have 66 classes and images around 50000 and my pc's ram is 12 gb my ram is not sufficient for the training of the images my question is does resolution of the images affects the accuracy of the model I am using convolutional neural networks.

Comment: It might affect as much as it would affect our vision. There is probably a limit for the model too. But what is the batch size you're using? Try using `generator` and `model.fit_generator()`. It's very usual when working with tons of images. Keras has a few options such as the ImageDataGenerator: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: i am just resizing the data into a particular resolution well during resizing all images are not resized because ram becoming full thats'y 
well can u tell what is min. resolultion of an image i can use to train my model?

Comment: Try online (incremental) learning algorithms. Instead of loading all images to memory at once, just do it for some images at a time as @DanielMöller by using batch size. You can resize only those much images on the fly. There's no thing as a minimum resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using convolutional neural networks with fully connected layer in the end for getting prediction probabilities, the input layer will have fixed size so you will need to preprocess all images to that size to feed to the network.

If you have images with size lesser than this size, you will need to interpolate and increase size upto this so no effect on memory by further reducing image size. So minimum resolution is the input convolutional layer size.

For your ram issue, depending on framework you are using, using queues properly should solve that issue no matter how large size images are. If the OOM error is during preprocessing, try reducing queue size so that only fraction of images are getting resized at a time to fit in memory. If OOM is during training, try reducing the batch size.

Comment: what is min. resolultion of an image i can use to train my model?